# How can I convert interface to struct from JSON?

Tags: json, go

I have a Go project that is unmarshalling JSON into the below struct:

```
type RespBody struct {
    Status string      `json:"status"` // Success or Error
    Data   interface{} `json:"data,omitempty"`
    Error  string      `json:"error,omitempty"`
}
```

The `Data` field is typically a `ReleaseResponse` type which is like so:

```
type ReleasesResponse struct {
    ReleaseElements      []ReleaseElement `json:"releaseElements,omitempty"`
    IsThreatValid        bool             `json:"isThreatValid,omitempty"`
    ThreatWarningMessage string           `json:"threatWarningMessage,omitempty"`
}
```

However I cannot figure out how to unmarshal into this type.  I've tried something like this:

```
    var respBody RespBody

            var dataBody struct {
                Data ReleasesResponse
            }


            if err := json.Unmarshal(getRespBody, &dataBody); err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You forgot to share the response JSON.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. Please include sufficient code and sample data to demonstrate the problem you're asking about (ideally, code that we can run to reproduce the issue).

Answer (score 1):

The unmarshaler cannot really guess the actual data you intend to use. There are several solutions to this problem, but they are all variations around having a different representation for marshaling/unmarshaling. For instance, you can do:

```
type RespBody struct {
    Status string      `json:"status"` // Success or Error
    Data   interface{} `json:"-"`
    DataMarshal json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
    Error  string      `json:"error,omitempty"`
}
```

Then, when you unmarshal, you have the `RespBody` partially filled, and `data` remains as a JSON object in `DataMarshal` field. When you decide the actual type of `Data` field, you can:

```
var data ReleaseResponse
json.Unmarshal(body.DataMarshal,&data)
body.Data=data
```